# Is storing key value cache (15kb JSON values) in MySQL database good practice?

Tags: caching

I am new to implementing caches.

The key is a simple string (i.e. 10 characters long). No collisions.

The value is a large string. Is storing this in a MySQL database looked down upon or is it fine?

Alternatives: Memory, File Sys, NoSQL. What do you think about them.

Thanks!

Comment: caching like 15kb go for memory

Comment: What if I have thousands of these 15kb?

Comment: I want them persistent, so file vs SQL

Answer (score 0):

I dont see any problem in doing this, older versions of mysql dont support json datatypes so you wont be able to perform queries over it, but in new mysql versions you can perform queries.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html